# Import specific columns from text-file into mysql.. is this possible?

Tags: mysql, import

I've just downloaded a bunch of text files from data.gov, and there are fields in the text file that I really don't need.

Is there a way to import columns [1,3] and leave the rest?

I figure I'll import using 'load data in file', but didn't see anything on the mysql page as to how to only import certain columns.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

The fields are delimited by ^. 
Just so I'm clear, if a line in the txt file is

```
00111^first column entry^second column entry^this would be the 3rd column
```

I am trying to get my mysql table to contain

```
first column entry | this would be the 3rd column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a table with a dummy column(s) which you drop after loading the file (assuming you don't have to load the file very often).

Something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file' INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^' (dummy_column1, column1, dummy_column2, column2);
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP dummy_column1;
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP dummy_column2;
```

Comment: Thanks trevor, I knew that was an option, but was hoping their was a way to do this right into mysql. looks like there isn't

Answer (score 2):

You can import the specific columns with:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'yourFile' INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^' (column1, @dummy, column3, @dummy);
```

Put all columns which you don't need in @dummy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Unix platform, you could filter the fields upstream.

```
cut -d^ -f2,4 mygovfile.dat > mytable.txt
```

To filter the first and third column, then import using your preferred method.
For instance

```
mysqlimport --local -uxxx -pyyy mydb --fields-terminated-by="^" mytable.txt ....
```

Comment: I'm not on unix for dev, and I was hoping for an option that was straight mysql instead of messing with the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common ways of dealing with this:

1. Import the data just as it is into a
   staging table, move what you need
   into your "real" tables, then
   truncate the staging table.
2. Use a text utility to snip out just
   what you need.

My text utility of choice is awk. A minimal awk script--which probably won't work for you without some tweaking--would look like this.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="^";OFS=",";}{print $2, $4}' test.dat
first column entry,this would be the 3rd column
```

What kind of tweaking? It usually involves taking care of embedded commas, single quotes, and double quotes.

This part

```
BEGIN { FS="^";OFS=",";}{print $2, $4}
```

is the whole awk program.

awk rocks.